# Resultant vector from three different location

Tags: calculus

I have three vectors in the xyz space.
How to compute the Resultant vector from these three vectors, are

0.000326  -0.00018  -0.00017

0.000365  -0.00016  -0.00017

-0.00015  -0.00018  -0.00039

and their start coordinates are

2.53493  2.47587  2.47282

2.54089  2.48301  2.47585

2.4791  2.47583  2.46097

Comment: The computation of the resultant vector (the sum) does not need the knowledge of any origin (start) point. Just add the three first entries, etc : $(0.000676,-0.00052,-0.00073)$

Comment: @JeanMarie, thanks, but I didn't get "add the three first entries." Is 
 (0.000676,−0.00052,−0.00073) the result I want?

Comment: Yes, plainly, it is what I meant, the three $x$ entries, the three $y$ entries, the three $z$ entries.